# Verilog error: Register is illegal in left-hand side of continuous assignment

Tags: verilog

I'm a verilog noob and I have to do this ALU for a processor but I get this error for this line:

assign SP_out = SP;

> "Register is illegal in left-hand side of continuous assignment"

I'm using modelsim.

```
module ALU(opcode,ra,rb,ra_out,cin,co,res,rst,clk,pc,npc,CCRin,CCRo,SP,SP_out);
  output [1:0] res; // result 
  input wire [7:0]pc;
  output reg [7:0] npc;
  input rst,clk;
  input wire cin;
  input wire [3:0] opcode;
  input wire[1:0] ra;
  input wire[1:0] rb;
  output reg[1:0] ra_out;
  input wire[7:0] SP; // testbench haygebli SP el mafroud yeb2a = 255
  output reg[7:0] SP_out;

  reg[255:0] dmem;

  input wire [3:0] CCRin;
  output reg [3:0] CCRo;
  output co;

  wire [2:0] result; //total result

  assign SP_out = SP;

  assign result = alu_out(ra,rb,cin); 
  assign res = result[1:0];
  assign co = result[2];



  function [2:0] alu_out;
   input [1:0] ra,rb;
   input cin;

  case (opcode)
    0: ;
    4: assign alu_out = ra + rb;
    5: assign alu_out = ra - rb;
    6: assign alu_out = ~(ra & rb);
    7: assign alu_out = {ra[1:0],cin};
    8: assign alu_out = {ra[0],cin,ra[1]};
    10: if (ra == 1)
          begin
         dmem[SP_out] = rb;
         SP_out = SP_out-1;
       end
     else
       begin
       SP_out = SP_out +1;
       rb = dmem[SP_out];
     end
    13: assign ra_out = rb;
    default: begin
    alu_out = 8'bxxxxxxxx; 
    npc = pc+1;


end
endcase 
endfunction
  always@( res)
   begin 
  if (res == 0)
     CCRo[0] = 1;
  else if ( res < 0)
   CCRo[1] = 1;
  else if (co == 1)
    CCRo[2] = 1;
  else if ( res < 0 & res > result)
    CCRo[3] = 1;
  else
    CCRo = CCRin;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`assign` statements are only legal on `wire` types, not `reg` types.

If you have a `reg`, then you want to assign it from a block:

```
always @* begin
   SP_out = SP;
end
```

Alternatively, remove the `reg` declaration from `SP_out` to treat it as a wire, then your assign statement will work.

Both options will behave in the exact same way.

Comment: Thanks! I put it in an always block and that did the trick. I have a question though If my output is a wire does that affect anything? (my TA told me all inputs must be wires and outputs must be regs)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I don't think there is any difference between an output wire and output reg. Inputs are always wire (but it doesn't matter because you don't assign them), but either type of output seems valid to me. I'm not sure why your TA would have said that.

Comment: I'm not sure either, Thank you so much tim!